# Store data from the SerialPort.ReadExisting() method in a variable?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I would like to read information from a device connected to a SerialPort. I did this previously using a form (code below) but I am trying to do it without one, just storing the information into an array of string.

Code used with a form:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender,  System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                string line = port.ReadExisting();              
                this.BeginInvoke(new LineReceivedEvent(LineReceived), line);
            }

        private delegate void LineReceivedEvent(string line);
        private void LineReceived(string line)
        {
            textBox3.AppendText(line);
        }
```

How far i got without a form (the DA method is allows to store variables within the program). I get the following error on the last line `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler'`.

```
protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
  {
    string selectedportname;
    DA.GetData(1, ref selectedportname);
    int selectedbaudrate;
    DA.GetData(2, ref selectedbaudrate);
    bool connecttodevice;
    DA.GetData(3, ref connecttodevice);
    bool sendtoprint;
    DA.GetData(3, ref sendtoprint);


    port = new SerialPort(selectedportname, selectedbaudrate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One); //Create the serial port
    port.DtrEnable = true;   //enables the Data Terminal Ready (DTR) signal during serial communication (Handshaking)
    port.Open();             //Open the port
    port.DataReceived += port.ReadExisting();                                             

  }
```

Comment: Even though you are not using a form you still need to assign a delegate with the proper signature to handle the DataReceived event

Comment: Post the code (at least the headings) of `LineReceived` and `ReadExisting`

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have added LineReceived in the code which I used with a form. ReadExisting is part of this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ReadExisting` is a method with the right parameters:

```
//port.DataReceived += port.ReadExisting();   
  port.DataReceived += port.ReadExisting;
```

But the error indicates it is returning a 'string' so there is more to solve here.

### Edit:

Looks like it should be:

```
  port.DataReceived += this.serialPort1_DataReceived;
```

Comment: thx Henk, this is only if i used the serialPort1_DataReceived method but I am trying not to use it and do it all within the SolveInstance method. Is that not possible?

Comment: Issues are getting crossed here. You need a method with a similar signature `(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)` or a lambda to attach to the Received event.